# Is there a general rule to find period of multiplied functions?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, fourier-series

We know that $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are both periodic and trigonometric functions and we also know its period interval. How can we find the period of the function $f(x)g(x)$?

Comment: Provided $$\dfrac{p_1}{p_2}$$ is rational. In that the resultant period must divide the LCM